# openshift inventory file define a node as a master node and infra-node

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

**Question 1** : is it possible to define a node as a master node and an infra-node ? and if possible how is this done in the inventory file ?

**Question 2** : do we have restrictions on where to put etcd , registries , routers ? or can we put them in the master nodes or infra-nodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/configuring_inventory_file.html#configuring-inventory-node-group-definitions)'s default Node Group Definition for openshift 3.11. "node-config-master-infra" is for your question 1. Question 2: node's capacity and dns-infrastructure are your restrictions.

In addition, [Here](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/release-3.11/inventory/hosts.localhost)'s all in one node example.

Moreover, I suggest to check [system/environment requirements](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/prerequisites.html#system-requirements).

Comment: can you please explain to me what is the restriction due to dns-infrastructure ?

Comment: For routes it should be possible to configure your dns to the infra-node

Comment: i'm new to openshift can you please elaborate ?

Comment: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/router/default_haproxy_router.html#customizing-the-default-routing-subdomain for routes you'll configure subdomain which should be pointed to infra-node